# How can I use erb in my ruby on rails view to make a bootstrap glyphicon a button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, erb

I want to use a bootstrap glyphicon as a link in my rails app.  To do this without a glyphicon I would use the link_to method:
    <%= link_to "up", like_post_path(post), method: :put %>

I basically want the "up" to be a glyphicon instead.  But I can not figure out how to add a link and still preserve the glyphicon as is.  Here is all the code in my erb view relevant to my desired button:

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-success" aria-label="vote up" type="button">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</a>
```

I want to make this button link to my like_post_path(post).  I've tried making the span into a button with the glyphicon classes, and a link_to method in the middle..didn't work.
I've tried making the a href="<% many different erb attempts %> and no luck with that either.  Can anyone tell me the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `content_tag`:

```
<%= button_to content_tag(:span, "", class: "glyphicon glyphicon-plus"), like_post_path(post), class: "btn btn-success" %>
```

You can also use it with `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:span, "", class: "glyphicon glyphicon-plus"), like_post_path(post), class: "btn btn-success", type: "button" %>
```

Or you can write the HTML code directly, and use the `raw` helper to avoid the ERB escape.

Comment: shouldn't the span-tags be filled with "nbsp;"?

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
<%= link_to like_post_path(post), method: :put do %>
<button class="btn btn-success" aria-label="vote up"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What's the sense of wrapping a button within a link?

Comment: @SimoneCarletti Yep i agree but it does the job :)